# Is a relation on which every element is related with itself alone transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

For example,

```
if A = {1,2,3} and R = {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}
```

is R transitive? If so, then would it be an order relation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's transitive; we usually call it "equality". And yes, it is also an order relation.

Comment: Is it symmetric as well?

Comment: Yes. It's **equality**. If $a=b$, then $b=a$.

Comment: I read that symmetric isn't the opposite of antisymmetric, so there could be a relation that is symmetric and antisymmetric at the same time, is it antisymmetric?

Comment: Yes, of course. Equality is antisymmetric.

Comment: So this is both equality and partial order?

Comment: Yes, equality is a partial order. Not a very useful one, though.

Answer (score 0):

The proof for transitivity is simple:
Let $a,b,c \in A$ and assume that $aRb$ and $bRc$. By definition of $R$, this implies $a=b$ and $b=c$, which implies $a=c$, thus $aRc$, so $R$ is transitive.

Proving antisymmetry and reflexivity is similiar, just remember that $aRb$ iff $a=b$, and substitute that in the definitions.